# Python replacements for RVM/Bundler/Capistrano

Tags: python, ruby, development-environment, env

I'm just moving over from Ruby/Rails development to Python/Django and i'm trying to find the  best replacements for RVM/Bundler/Capistrano but it seems to be a total mess?

I've found these so far:

- pythonbrew
- virtualenv
- envwrapper
- pip
- easyinstall
- setuptools

For capistrano I've found Fabric which seems to fit fairly well?

I've found some articles describing how to set up virtualenv/pip/fabric but it seems everyone is moving over to pythonbrew? Which ones should i pick? Also it seems pip/virtualenv is integrated fairly well but if pythonbrew is a better choice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used pip/virtualenv/fabric extensively and am happy with it. You can't go wrong with this choice.

I haven't used pythonbrew however, so I can't do any relative comparison.

Comment: My biggest concern with just going with that is that I've read about some people having a lot of problems with using multiple python versions (symlink problems).

Also i really like the idea of having the python installations isolated from the rest of the system and the ease of reinstalling if something breaks.

But if virtualenv is a much better choice or if they complement each other i'll definitely go with virtualenv.

Comment: virtualenv of course creates isolated python installations. I don't know of anyone that had problems with multiple versions.

Comment: I settled with virtualenv after trying them both out. Pythonbrew feels a bit buggy on os x.

Answer (score 3):

pip is 'the' tool for Python packages, replacing easy_install. Most people are using virtualenv for multiple python environments.